# PnP Provisioning Engine - Canvas Column for Multi Column Modern Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, modern-pages, remote-provisioning

I have a Modern Page that utilises 1 section with 6 columns (factor is 2 for each). There is one webpart per column.

When extracting the template, the 6 canvas controls are all placed into 1 Sections controls. Upon re-applying the template it fails (Index Bounds) because the Column attribute the CanvasControl stills reflects the column based on a 6 column grid.

It is my interpretation from the schema documentation that CanvasColumn element would be able to correct this. The schema refers to CanvasColumn element, however there does not seem to be any reference to what its parent should be. Upon inspecting code I cannot find an implementation for it (either extract or apply).

Could someone please advise the status of this element and how can be used or alternatively a workaround that will allow me to provision a Modern Page with more than 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the code on Github and cross referencing the schema XSD. It would appear that this is infact not implemented.

I have raised an issue on the GitHub repository.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Provisioning-Schema/issues/326